# I can't run a program in C++ builder 2010 and was reminded of error 5 and warning 1

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010

I downloaded programs from rtklib.com and run the program in C++ builder 2010.I open a file called rtknavi.cbproj and run it but CB 2010 reminds me that there are errors. Maybe there are something wrong with header file.
The error message of CB said:

```
[BCC32 Error] maskoptdlg.h(5): E2209 Unable to open include file 'System.Classes.hpp' 
[BCC32 Error] maskoptdlg.h(6): E2209 Unable to open include file 'Vcl.Controls.hpp'
[BCC32 Error] maskoptdlg.h(7): E2209 Unable to open include file 'Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp'
[BCC32 Error] maskoptdlg.h(8): E2209 Unable to open include file 
'Vcl.Forms.hpp'
[BCC32 Error] maskoptdlg.h(9): E2209 Unable to open include file 'Vcl.ExtCtrls.hpp'
```

It is said that I should add or modify path but how to do. I just want to run the program and see the results. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++Builder 2010 these includes are invalid: the `Vcl.` and `System.` prefixes did not exist yet. For XE2 onwards, the include/unit names got that treatment (to support FireMonkey) and it is expected/recommended to use the *fully qualified* name of the unit in new code.

So, in summary: you opened a project that was intended for XE2 or later. You need to remove the `Vcl.` or `System.` prefixes from those `#include` directives (and maybe after that you will encounter some other errors, but if they are units from Embarcadero then the solution would be the same).

Comment: Yes, it was XE2 that added **Unit Scope Names** to the filenames of all of the RTL, VCL, and FMX units.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It solves the problem perfectly. After masking vcl. and system. prefixes, the program becomes alive in Builder 2010.

Comment: @BryanYU just click on the check mark in the left bar of the answers, below the up/down vote buttons.